# wrapping string values in vector with quotes and comma separator

Tags: r

I have a dataframe where the second column is a series of string descriptors that are separated with white space.

```
col.x          col.y 
company1       science data tech food social 
company2       social tech industry data
```

Is there an easy way wrap each string value in the second column in quotes and separate with a comma to look like this?

```
col.x          col.y 
company1       "science", "data", "tech", "food", "social" 
company2       "social", "tech", "industry", "data"
```

Comment: And what is the aim/purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `gsub` to insert the quotes and comma - capture the word (`(\\w+)`) as a group, in the replacement, wrap the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group with double quotes followed by a comma, and then wrap the whole expression with `trimws` to remove the lagging `,` at the end of the string

```
df1$col.y <- trimws(gsub('(\\w+)', '"\\1",', df1$col.y), whitespace = ",")
```

-output

```
> df1
     col.x                                       col.y
1 company1 "science", "data", "tech", "food", "social"
2 company2        "social", "tech", "industry", "data"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(col.x = c("company1", "company2"), 
col.y = c("science data tech food social", 
"social tech industry data")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: akrun always a life saver!